# wxpython and splash screen

Tags: python, wxpython, splash-screen

I am trying to set up a splash screen for my gui executable using wxpython.  Essentially what I am doing is loading a bunch of databases first.  Then I set up my wx GUI window.  These two processes take about 35 seconds.

When i start the code, I want a splash screen to show up and stay up until the GUI is up and running (after the 35 seconds).

I have looked at this:  [How to adapt my current splash screen to allow other pieces of my code to run in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892327/how-to-adapt-my-current-splash-screen-to-allow-other-pieces-of-my-code-to-run-in)

This doesn't quite help because I load my databases outside of my wx code.

For Example:

```
Imports
Database loading
class (my wx)
```

I do the database loading outside of the wx because i have multiple classes referencing the databases.  I am fairly new to python -- so please easy on me :)

Any help with setting up a splash screen to start before my database loading and stop when my GUI in wx loads?  Thanks!

Comment: You can place database loading into a thread and use a variable (a counter, e.g.) that will be incremented as databases are loaded, and your splash screen will read that variable, displaying gauge until everything is done.

Comment: ^ You shouldn't do that, better use wx.CallAfter to update the GUI, it's easier and less error-prone.

Comment: I have been reading about wx.CallAfter, but not sure how i would implement it.  Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are going about this a little backwards. Put the loading of the databases into the init of the frame or the wx.App. But before you do the loading, show the splashscreen. Then do the loading. Then when the loading is done, do the GUI loading and right before you reach the Frame's Show() method, close the splash screen.

Comment: this sounds good, but will the databases (variables and lists) be able to be used in all the other classes as well?  For instance, I have about 4 different classes that all access the same variables/lists.  This is why i have the databases loaded at the beginning of my .py file rather than inside a specific class

Comment: I don't know how your code is arranged. I typically put my database code into a model.py file and load it up at the beginning and then access it with my controller which is imported into all the other classes. My medialocker project might give you some clues about that: https://bitbucket.org/driscollis/medialocker . I also wrote about an earlier version here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/10/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-an-intro-to-mvc-and-crud/

Comment: In my code I like to use [pubsub](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub) to deal with DB I/O because modularity was a design requirement. I init my DB with my frame but all other DB calls are done via pubsub messages. That way my classes don't even need to know my DB exists, only how to request and receive data. Just remember that pubsub messages are asynchronous!